# Error on datatable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm facing some problems trying of create a dynamic table using datatable.js.

```
    mytable.DataTable({ 
    "columns":[
            {"title": "col1", data: "col1"},
            {"title": "col1", data: "col2"},
            {"title": "col1", data: "col3"},
            {"title": "col1", data: "col4"},
            {"title": "col1", data: "col4"}
        ],
    "data":data
});
```

The problem is this appear like this:
[image]

And when I try to order appear like this:
[image]

How I could do ordering at first?
Thx in advance!

Comment: are your red/green/blue icons inside a datatable column ? If yes, your first screenshot is strange as we don't see the column headers above the icons....and what is your need ? Order at the loading ? On each column exactly ?

Comment: Thx for answer me. The first question is yes, but i don't understand why name columns is showing in that way. The second question is try to remain column name above all the every columns

Comment: if you can share the complete code used for generating your datatable with the 3 icons, i will be able to help you...do you use render datatable function for displaying the icons, do you load a empty column then in jquery dynamically add the icons etc...i don't  know what code you did, difficult to help you ;-)  So if you share your complete code, will help me to help you ;-)

Comment: I found how I can get the column names fixed with this: 
$('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner tablaPreguntas_wrapper').attr('style','box-sizing: content-box; /*! width: 0px; */ padding-right: 0px;');
    $('.table tablaPreguntas_wrapper').attr('style','/*! width: 0px; */ margin-left: 0px;');
But i dont know how i can replace this in the code without lost configuration of the other tables.